# Parsing custom HTML tags

Tags: html, parsing, custom-tag

I have custom tags like this:

```
<!--a_word_with_numbers2323-->
    Some content here
<!--/a_word_with_numbers2323-->
```

I'm trying to find all the tags with this pattern:

```
<!--[a-z_]+[0-9]*-->.*<!--/[a-z_]+[0-9]*-->
```

And it's working.

But, If I have something like this:

```
<!--a_word_with_numbers2323-->
    <--some_embedded_tag-->asafssaf<--/some_embedded_tag-->
<!--/a_word_with_numbers2323-->
```

How to write regexp that can prevent from embedded tags. So that, at first, inner tags would be found and then, after I delete these tags (replace with empty string), outer tags would be found. I want something like this:

```
<!--[a-z_]+[0-9]*-->[^(<!--)]*<!--/[a-z_]+[0-9]*-->
```

Where `(<!--)` should be interpreted as a whole expression, but not as restricted characters ( < ! - and )

I tried to google, but I didn't find anything useful and I know that I should not parse HTML with regexps, but I'm parsing custom tags, not HTML.

Comment: Please don't.... Someone please link to the famous answer... I'm on mobile.

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Yes, I have seen this question. These are custom tags without any attributes. All of them have unique names and are generated by code according to one pattern. I just need to find the rule where I can identify text without these consecutive characters:  <!--

Comment: Most XML/HTML *should* be able to parse HTML comments, which is what your custom "tags" are.